# Revert commit with Large file and resolve binary merge conflict

Tags: git, github, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution, git-revert

I want to `push` my commits to GitHub, but it doesn't allow me because the file `Extras.pkl` is too large. I have (accidentally) added that file 7 commits back in `dfa4bfe`, but is currently nowhere to find in my repository (it appears to be deleted).  `git revert dfa4bfe` prompts

```
warning: Cannot merge binary files: MuonRate/nHits_distribution.png (HEAD vs. parent of dfa4bfe... Add HRV split graph and z direction dist) 
error: could not revert dfa4bfe... Add HRV split graph and z direction dist
```

That is because there were 2 images in that same commit (one is creating the conflict).

I used `git checkout --ours/theirs "MuonRate/nHits_distribution.png"` to assign the version manually and used `git add` and `git commit` to commit these. But then I get the following:

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 9 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
You are currently reverting commit dfa4bfe.

Untracked files:
        #some unimportant files

nothing added to commit but untracked files present
```

Note the last 3th and last line. When I use `git commit -m "empty commit to escape revert" --allow-empty`, then the line `You are currently reverting commit dfa4bfe.` disappears. But then if I `git push origin main`, I get the exact same error saying that the file `Extras.pkl` is too large.

QUESTION: How can I undo the commit from `Extras.pkl` and resolve the binary issue?

Git log:

```
* da43e5a (HEAD -> main) empty commit to escape revert
* e8d3f7a add .gitignore
* 633b6f2 Delete extrapkl
* 9f2366b .
* e2c9712 Add mplstyle
* b3702dc Rerun and delete filters for V9
* dfa4bfe Add HRV split graph and z direction dist
* 76bee13 Plot nHist complete
* 7f227ea First histogram of nHits
* b82b78b Create Multi directory data loop
etc.
```

**Note:**, none of my commits during the reverting appears in the history.
The problems lies in the commit `dfa4bfe Add HRV split graph and z direction dist`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [the github page regarding sensitive information](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository), I have resolved the issue. For future reference and others:

Skip the following 2 steps if the problem is within your local repo:

1. `git clone https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPOSITORY`
2. `cd YOUR-REPOSITORY`

Change `PATH-TO-YOUR-FILE-WITH-SENSITIVE-DATA` to your file location, but leave the quotation marks.

3. `git filter-branch --force --index-filter \ "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch PATH-TO-YOUR-FILE-WITH-SENSITIVE-DATA" \ --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all`
4. Press enter twice
5. `git push ORIGIN MAIN`